# Swift 4 Firebase display group of users on TableView

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview

How i can display users with unique role on TableView. For example i want to display users only with role "user", or only with role "guest".

my User model:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class User: NSObject {

var id: String?
var name: String?
var login: String?
var email: String?
var profileImageUrl: String?
var role: String?
var isOnline: String?
init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.isOnline = dictionary["isOnline"] as? String
    self.id = dictionary["userID"] as? String
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    self.login = dictionary["username"] as? String
    self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    self.role = dictionary["role"] as? String
}
}
```

My Firebase user model:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simple filter the array of users by the role.

`self.guests = self.users.filter({$0.role == "guest"})`

Then display the list of guests just like any other UITableView.

Comment: it works for me, thanks! One more thing... and if i want display few roles, how can i write filter? For example i want display guest and user

Comment: self.guests = self.users.filter({$0.role == "guest" || $0. role == "user"}) 
this should work but... it doesn't

Comment: That should work, but you would have to remove the space after the second $0.